# Can anyone confirm that phpMyAdmin AllowNoPassword works with MySQL databases?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, passwords, phpmyadmin

I have a version of phpMyAdmin located on my local Apache server.

I am trying to login without a password however phpMyAdmin keeps throwing the warning:

> Login without a password is forbidden by configuration (see AllowNoPassword)

However in my **config.php** file for phpMyAdmin I have set:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE;
```

So I don't know why the message is still appearing.

Comment: Checks if mysql is running, D'oh!

Comment: This works for me immediatley in CentOS 7, but not CentOS 6. Can't figure it out :(. PS: It would be nice if we knew the OS you were on!, but its a little late lol

Answer (score 140, accepted):

1. **Copy** `config.sample.inc.php` to `config.inc.php`.

   In most cases you will find the config file

   - on linux: `/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php`
   - on mac: `/Library/WebServer/Documents/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php`
2. If you are trying to log in as root, you should have the following lines in your config:

   > $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
   >   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;

Comment: In CentOS 7: `/etc/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php`

Comment: this should be added in two places according to this: https://docs.oseems.com/general/web/phpmyadmin/enable-login-without-password and it should be $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true; NOT $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPasswordRoot'] = true;

Comment: I'm going to check the obvious first and ask if you remembered to copy your config.sample.inc to config.inc. ??? Why to make config.php ? There is alread config,inc.php

Comment: Works for me... Thanks :)

Comment: nothing worked for me then i followed this document and changed password of root. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-reset-your-mysql-or-mariadb-root-password-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: In manjaro/Arch, the file will be located under /etc/webapps/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php

Answer (score 10):

According to this: https://www.simplified.guide/phpmyadmin/enable-login-without-password

This `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE;` should be added twice in `/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php`

```
if (!empty($dbname)) {
    // other configuration options
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE;
    // it should be placed before the following line
    $i++;
}

// other configuration options
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE;
```

Answer (score 7):

I tested the statement:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPasswordRoot'] = true;
```

It did not work out for me.

Instead

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

worked.

Thanks!

Comment: error clearly states `AllowNoPassword` needs to be `true` not `AllowNoPasswordRoot`. but documentation doesn't mention this. setting `AllowNoPassword` to `true` works indeed.

Answer (score 5):

Yes not working! I spent whole day with this stupid phpMyAdmin. Just add a new user with a password

1 - Login to mysql or mariadb `mysql -u root -p`

2 - Run these SQL commands to create a new user with all permissions (or grant your custom permissions)

```
CREATE USER 'someone'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'someone'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

2 - Go to `/etc/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php` and change this:

```php
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']          = 'someone';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']      = 'password';
```

WARNING: This config is for localhost development server only, If you're running a production server you must use strong credentials and not setting user pass in config.inc.php

Comment: thanks but the first part is sufficent , why the second part?

Comment: if you're on localhost and want to save some time, but it's not working either these days, I 've deleted the outdated phpMyAdmin... now I'm using DBeaver instead.

Answer (score 4):

You might have made the same silly mistake that I did, by not removing the // making it a comment.

The line should be like this, but not as a comment.

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE;
```

Answer (score 3):

**Make sure you don't add or uncomment the AllowNoPassword option after the $i++ line.**

/* Uncomment the following to enable logging in to passwordless accounts,
     * after taking note of the associated security risks. */

```
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE;
```

Answer (score 3):

Just in file `/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php`, uncomment or add the line(if not there),

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE;
```

It works just Awesome!

if you have any doubt restart apache.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Cheers!!!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.
Edit config.inc.php didn't work, similary as reinstall phpmyadmin, apache or mysql.
Only way is using password to log in to phpmyadmin.

How to set password:

1. Do everything from below script:

`sudo mysql_secure_installation`

2. Run:

`sudo mysql`

3. Change authentication method of password for root and set password:

`mysql> SELECT user,authentication_string,plugin,host FROM mysql.user;`

4. Run:

`mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

5. `exit` mysql.

Now you can log to phpmyadmin correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem here, then I reinstalled `mysql` and it worked.

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-common mysql-client
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a same problem, and I solved my problem.
First go to `config.default.php` and change

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
```

to

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

Comment: where is config.default.php?

Answer (score 2):

> ### login without a password is forbidden by configuration (see allownopassword)

In `ubuntu 20.04` and `MYSQL 8.0.x` I had the same problem and I tried to allow PHPMyAdmin not to using passwords.

1. So for this you can open the config file by using this command:

```
sudo nano /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
```

2. Then use **CTRL+w** to find `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword']` in PHPMyAdmin`s config file:

```
/* Uncomment the following to enable logging in to passwordless accounts,
     * after taking note of the associated security risks. */
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE;
```

3. Uncomment the line by removing the `//` like this:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE;
```

4. Use **CTRL+o** to save the file and then **CTRL+x** to exit from the file.
5. After that restart the MySQL by this command:

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

6. Try to access PHPMyAdmin in your local `http://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin/`

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of trials I found the following solution.

This will work if you copied all phpmyadmin files in /var/www

go to your copied location of phpmyadmin folder in /var/www

```
copy the config.sample.inc.php file as config.inc.php
```

edit in config.inc.php the following line:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

(In original file it was false, change it as true and save it.)

Then you will be able to login phpmyadmin without password.

Answer (score 1):

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE;
```

yes the above answer is correct, but it's not secure, you can login **root user** directlyinto `phpMyAdmin`.

If you want to create new user with password and give grant permission, execute the below command in MySQL on terminal, 
Login into your server on terminal,

```
  # mysql

 mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO  'user-name'@'%'  IDENTIFIED BY  'password'   REQUIRE NONE WITH GRANT OPTION MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

For me I had to set the auth type to config in addition to the setting the allow no password option in the config.inc.php file.

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Others may find, as I did, (working in OS X 10.10.1) that the situation for MAMP PRO (at least in the current release, 3.0.7.3, is different.

All my attempts to apply the remedies suggested here failed. Upon examining the PHP error log I discovered that the index.php that is operating (in `/Libary/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/index.php` -- at line 43, is deciding NOT to go to the `config.inc.php` that is discussed here (at `/Applications/MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php`) but rather to `/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php`.

Furthermore, there is no such file there (after a 'successful' install of MAMP PRO), so I'm stuck with the error, and furtherfuthermore, every time I try to put the correct file there, when I restart MAMP PRO, it is not there anymore - something is automatically refreshed to eliminate the `config.inc.php` I'm putting there. My workaround for now is to do this in MAMP instead of MAMP PRO.

Answer (score 0):

I had to install MariaDB. I am using OpenSUSE LINUX Leap 15 and had to execute these commands:

```
sudo zypper update
sudo zypper install mariadb mariadb-client mariadb-tools
sudo systemctl start mysql
sudo systemctl enable mysql //enable auto start at boot time3
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

[Source](https://www.linuxbabe.com/opensuse/apache-mariadb-php7-lamp-opensuse-leap-42-2#null).

Answer (score 0):

It works; just thought this would be helpful to someone in the future.

If you are working with MAMP, as a security measure, the `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;` usually will be missing in the `config.inc.php` file so if you want to use phpMyAdmin without a password for **root** then simply add it preferably after the `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowDeny']['rules'] = array();` statement.

Then Restart your server just to be sure and you will be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

After lots of struggle I found here you go:

1. open folder  -> xampp
2. then open    -> phpmyadmin
3. finally open -> config.inc

```
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = ''; /* YOU MUST FILL IN THIS FOR COOKIE AUTH! */
```

4. Put SHA256 inside single quotations like this one

830bbca930d5e417ae4249931838e2c70ca0365044268fa0ede75e33aff677de

```
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = '830bbca930d5e417ae4249931838e2c70ca0365044268fa0ede75e33aff677de
';
```

I found this when I was downloading updated version of phpmyadmin. I wish this solution help you. [image]

Answer (score 0):

My problem was in config.inc.php
`<?` changed to `<?php`

Answer (score 0):

```
vim /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
```

or

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
```

uncomment this below line

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE;
```

Then, exit and save the file using the following command,

```
:wq
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to https://stackoverflow.com/a/5908864/1490667
In CentOS7, user 'apache' runs httpd, thus make sure user 'apache' has permission to read /etc/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php.

Answer (score -1):

**According to this**: https://drgamerss.blogspot.com/2024/01/how-to-login-without-password-in.html

Recently i have solve the same issue after watching many tutorials
Just copy and paste the config.inc.php file from above and paste it in your file now you are able log in with the **root** username and press on Go button.

In case

```
This $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE; should be added twice in /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php

if (!empty($dbname)) {
// other configuration options
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE;
// it should be placed before the following line
$i++;}

// other configuration options
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).