# How do I access PHPMyAdmin in Ubuntu?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to log into phpmyadmin however when I type username as "root" and password as blank, I get the error:

```
Login without a password is forbidden by configuration
```

I had a look at the accepted answer here: [Can anyone confirm that phpMyAdmin AllowNoPassword works with MySQL databases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908752/can-anyone-confirm-that-phpmyadmin-allownopassword-works-with-mysql-databases)

I uncommented the line (in `/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php`)  :

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE;
```

but to no avail

**Any help would be appreciated.**

[image]

Comment: Have you installed PHPMyAdmin?

Comment: @ChristianMark Yes :)

Comment: It would be worth checking you are accessing the right one. If you rename an index file in the same folder (assuming it is the vhost for the application itself), does your phpMyAdmin stop working? If not, you may have more than one installation.

Comment: @ChristianMark It opens up to the login page :) I tried `root` and blank there. No use :)

Comment: Ahhh.. so you are trying to access MySQL thru your phpmyadmin?

Comment: @ChristianMark Yes. As a part of my college project, yes :)

Comment: Ubuntu? Try to [reset your password](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16556497/how-to-change-the-mysql-root-password/16556534#16556534) and see what happens.

Comment: @ChristianMark Instead of blank, I must provide a password? :)

Comment: @LittleChild, yes. I would suggest that.

Comment: Wait, did you restart the mysql service in the terminal? the changes in your config file might still don't apply to your current MySQL/PHPmyAdmin

Comment: @ChristianMark Done, sir ! Worked like a charm. Set the new password to 'root', too. Format this as an answer and I shall gladly accept it :)

Comment: @ChristianMark [Proof](http://snag.gy/VgH2I.jpg) :D

Comment: You could be editing the wrong configuration. Try breaking the config purposely if it also breaks the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to reset your password in your MySQL like this:

Set / change / reset the MySQL root password on Ubuntu Linux. Enter the following lines in your terminal.

1. Stop the MySQL Server.

   `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop`
2. Start the mysqld configuration.

   `sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables &`
3. Login to MySQL as root.

   `mysql -u root mysql`
4. Replace YOURNEWPASSWORD with your new password!

> UPDATE user SET
>       Password=PASSWORD('YOURNEWPASSWORD') WHERE User='root'; FLUSH
>       PRIVILEGES; exit;

**Note: This method is not regarded as the securest way of resetting the password. However it works.**

References:

1. [Set / Change / Reset the MySQL root password on Ubuntu Linux](http://ubuntu.flowconsult.at/en/mysql-set-change-reset-root-password/)
2. [How to Reset the Root Password](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html)