# Cannot find phmymyadmin.config.php in Mac

Tags: macos, phpmyadmin

I want to login in Mac without using a password for Phpmyadmin

I can't login in my mac and I can't find the place to edit the configuration as mentioned in the following question:
[Can anyone confirm that phpMyAdmin AllowNoPassword works with MySQL databases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908752/can-anyone-confirm-that-phpmyadmin-allownopassword-works-with-mysql-databases/28228786)

Comment: it is in your phpmyadmin folder. the same folder where you have all the php files for phpmyadmin. Probably a subfolder of your webroot

Comment: can you specify me the folder, please?

Comment: Are you using MAMP or a similar tool it might not be in the spot you might expect. Are you using anything like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of sal answer, the path for my macSeiora is

/usr/local/etc/phpmyadmin.config.inc.php. thank you guys

Answer (score 1):

Check in:

```
.../phpmyadmin[version#]/config.inc.php
```

The '...' will depend on how you install the app. It might be in the webroot or within MAMP or XAMPP etc. Some more [phpmyadmin explanation here](https://cloudconfusing.com/2018/02/05/how-to-increase-the-file-size-limit-in-phpmyadmin/).

Answer (score 0):

If you simply downloaded the official source from phpmyadmin.net and uncompressed it in your web root, you'll have to create the `config.inc.php` file yourself (in the main phpMyAdmin folder that you've uncompressed). You can see more detailed instructions in the documentation: https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#manually-creating-the-file

If you've used some prepackaged kit such as MAMP or XAMPP, they sometimes move the file around, but their documentation should provide a pretty clear indication of that.